# How can I change the range of duplicates from month to day?

Tags: mysql, sql

mysql is

```
SELECT date_format(dt.d, '%Y-%m') as date_list,
      COUNT(distinct c.id) AS cnt       
    FROM date_t dt
    LEFT OUTER JOIN login_logs c on dt.d = DATE(c.reg_date)
    WHERE LEFT(dt.d,7) BETWEEN '2021-05-01' AND '2022-04-25'
    GROUP BY date_list
    ORDER BY date_list;
```

the result i want is,

```
c.id is 2022-04-01 , 2022-04-02 => count 2
```

but I am getting:

```
c.id is 2022-04 => count 1
```

how can I change distinct 'c.id' daily check ?

Comment: Please add sample data and expected outcome as text and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You are grouping data by year and month. If you want data in a per day granuality, group it accordingly.

Comment: i know data in a per day granuality, group it accordingly. but forced to use month, 
so , I want to use monthly data as the sum of daily data.  Is there no way?

Comment: 'I want to use monthly data as the sum of daily data.' - explain how this is different to grouping by month.